# Angular2 RC1 error "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Tags: http, angular, promise

I have a problem with angular 2 rc1 http get method:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

```
public getMessages() {
    return this.http.get('url').map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

then:

```
export class BaMsgCenter {
  public messages;
  public data_error: Boolean = false;
  constructor(private _baMsgCenterService:BaMsgCenterService) {
      this.messages = this._baMsgCenterService.getMessages().subscribe(
        (messages: Array<any>) => { 
          debugger;
          let result:Array<Message> = [];
          if (messages) {
            messages.forEach((message) => {
              result.push(
                 new Message(message[0], 
                          message[1],
                          message[2],
                          message[3],
                          message[4])
                 );
            });
          }
        return messages; 
        },
      err => { this.data_error = true}
        );
      }
}
```

Message class:

```
export class Message {
    id: number;
    message: string;
    send_date: string;
    status: number;
    from: string;
}
```

Error is in line: `new Message(message[0], (...)` . 
Probably this is connected with promise, but I don't have idea how to fix it. 
I want to parse json array to object, like:

```
[[1,"Title",1468669921000,0,"Siva"],[2,"Title",1468669934000,0,"Siva2"]]
```

Some idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Message` class does not have a constructor. You should write:

```
export class Message {
   constructor(public id: number,
       public message: string,
       public send_date: string,
       public status: number,
       public from: string) {}
}
```